# Achartengine bar chart labels

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine, label

I'm working on a bargraph with achartengine, and I would like to put upon the bars custom values, instead of using setDisplayChartValues: is that possible?

It's because all the bars in the chart are clickable, so i made clickable a bar even if it is tall zero, adding 3 units: i must not show 3, but 0.

hope this is clear and you can help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add annotations instead of the regular chart values:

```
// add an annotation for each bar
series.addAnnotation("text", x, y);
```

You can download a version including this feature [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).